# How to change time picker's format independent of language

Tags: flutter, timepicker

Anyone knows how I can use the AM/PM format of the time picker in any language?
The app has english & romanian languages, when in romanian the time picker it uses the 24 hour format, though I need AM/PM.

I didn't found any way to set a locale to it, so I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Filip didn't edit his answer, I will put an answer myself with the solution.

showTimePicker requires both setting alwaysUse24HourFormat to true and changing the locale to en-US in the builder method of the function.

Doing one without the either doesn't do anything.

So, the proper solution is:

```
 showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) => MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
      child: Localizations.override(
        context: context,
        locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
        child: child!,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

There is an open Github issue aswell, [for this issue.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54839)

Answer (score 0):

The `TimePickerDialog` [gets its format](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c860cba910319332564e1e9d470a17074c1f2dfd/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart#L2172) from `MediaQuery.of(context)`.
As shown in the [documentation for showTimePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showTimePicker.html) you can pass a `builder` to `showTimePicker` to force 24 hour format.

You can use the current `Locale` to pick the time format.

```dart
final time = showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: const TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 47),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
  Locale locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
  final force24HourFormat = locale.countryCode == 'RO';
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        alwaysUse24HourFormat: force24HourFormat,
      ),
      child: child!,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but setting the parameter alwaysUse24HourFormat doesn't work if the locale is Locale("ro", "Ro"). 
I went through the documentation and found out about Localizations.override constructor which paired with alwaysUse24HourFormat: true it works.
Separately they don't work.
Also found a Github with the issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54839

Comment: You can edit your answer to include Localizations.override like in this comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54839#issuecomment-628767595

And I will mark it as answer.